# How to create a view for a nested serializer with foreign keys in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I got this code, but I can't find a way to create a view that retrieve the allergies a patient has.

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_type = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    creation_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)


class Allergie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="X")


class PatientAllergies(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, related_name="patient_allergies", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    allergie = models.ForeignKey(Allergie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    professional_contract = models.ForeignKey(ProfessionalContract, null=True ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can span a `ManyToManyField` relation over your `PatientAllergies` model that acts as a *junction table*:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_type = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    allergies = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Allergie',
        through='PatientAllergies'
    )

# …
```

You can then for a `Patient` object `p` with:

```
p.allergies.all()
```

An alternative is to filter the `Allergie` objects with:

```
Allergie.objects.filter(patientallergies__patient=p)
```

or with the `ManyToManyField`:

```
Allergie.objects.filter(patient=p)
```

Comment: thanks, what about if I want to get a patient object that has a field that contains the allergies with id and name?